# Why do group actions necessarily imply homeomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

In reading Hatcher (p135), I see that an element of a group acting on a space is a homeomorphism.  Working from the definition of group action, I don't see why this would necessarily be true.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Because the inverse group element gives you the inverse function?

Comment: But, the relationship between group elements and the homeomorphisms is a homomorphism (not an isomorphism).

Comment: In order to further the discussion, it's probably best that you add more to your post (for instance, add a picture of pg. 135 of Hatcher).

Comment: @user54301 I think you're conflating things. A group action is a homomorphism from $G$ to $Aut(X)$, and this need not be an isomorphism of groups; but this *does* mean that each $g\in G$ is sent to an autohomeomorphism of $X$!

Comment: If a group is acting on a space, then it (necessarily) must be using the morphisms for this space (hence the group elements must correspond to continuous functions).  The identity map is the image of the identity element (and there are inverse group elements), so the maps corresponding to $g$ and $g^{-1}$ must compose to be the identity map, and hence are homeomorphisms (continuous maps with inverses).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: a continuous map with an inverse is not necessarily a homeomorphism. E.g., consider the identity map between $\Bbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology and $\Bbb{Z}$ with the indiscrete topology.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Luckily of course the maps corresponding to $g$ and $g^{-1}$ *are* continuous, so Rob's (quite correct) point is not a problem here. Still, for the OP this is worth clarifying.

Comment: @Noah, yes thanks for the clarification. I phrased my question sloppily, at best.

Comment: @user54301 Does my answer clarify things?

Comment: @Noah.  I need a bit of time to work thru your answer...

Comment: @RobArthan I agree, I should have made it clear that I was using that both maps are continuous in the parenthetical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Note that what I call "$Aut(X)$," Hatcher calls "$Homeo(X)$."

It doesn't make sense to say "a group acting on a space is a homeomorphism". A homeomorphism is a single map, from one space to another (possibly the same space).

What *is* true is, that if $G$ acts on $X$, then for each $g\in G$ the map $$act_g: X\rightarrow X: x\mapsto gx$$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $X$.

Why is this? Well, by definition $act_g$ is a continuous map, so we just need to show that it has a continuous inverse. Consider $act_{g^{-1}}$. This is again a continuous map from $X$ to $X$, and we have $act_g\circ act_{g^{-1}}=id=act_{g^{-1}}\circ act_g$ (since $gg^{-1}x=(gg^{-1}x=ex=x=ex=(g^{-1}g)x=g^{-1}gx$).

---

There is a sense in which a group acting on a space is a single map: namely,

- An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is a group homomorphism $h: G\rightarrow Sym(X)$.
- An action of a group $G$ on a *topological space* $X$ is a group homomorphism $h: G\rightarrow Aut(X)$, where "$Aut(X)$" is the group of autohomeomorphisms of $X$ (that is, homeomorphisms from $X$ to itself).

So in this sense, we can speak of a group action as a single map, and ask whether or not it is an isomorphism of groups (usually it is not). However, if we think of the *individual maps* making up the group action - formally, the elements of the image of $h$ - then each of these is indeed a homeomorphism from $X$ to itself. I've shown above how to deduce this from the axioms of group actions; if you define a group action on a space as a group homomorphism to $Aut(X)$, though, this becomes even easier, since *by definition* any element of the image is an element of $Aut(X)$ and hence an autohomeomorphism.

Comment: sorry I forgot homeomophisms are the isomorphisms and not just morphisms for topological spaces.

Comment: @Noah.  Got it. Thanks.

Comment: It's not correct that a group always acts by homeomorphisms on a space. That feels like a "too much category theory" trap. You have to assert that the group action is by continuous maps, otherwise there's no reason for them to be continuous.

Comment: @MattSamuel The definition of a group acting on a space that I've seen **is** that it acts via homeomorphisms . . . (And I believe that Hatcher demands this as well.)

Comment: @Noah That's a continuous group action. There's nothing that says that a group action in a topological space must be continuous. It's a set after all. I think that is the core of the OP's confusion. It's true that nothing algebraic implies that it must act by homeomorphisms.

Comment: @MattSamuel With respect, that's wrong in the context of this question. Note that the OP is talking about Hatcher, and in this context, what I've written is correct. See page 71 of Hatcher: "Given a group $G$ and a space $Y$ , then an action of $G$
on $Y$ is a homomorphism $\rho$ from $G$ to the group $Homeo(Y)$ of all homeomorphisms
from $Y$ to itself." I believe that for Hatcher, continuous group actions are relevant when we have a topology *on $G$*, as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_group_action.

Comment: @Noah Of course it's correct in Hatcher, I'm saying the OP probably didn't see that definition.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If we use the definition of a group action as a continuous function $G \times X \to X$, is $act_g$ still continuous?

Comment: @Twink Any "slice" of a continuous map is continuous: if $f:A\times B\rightarrow C$ is continuous (for $A,B,C$ topological spaces), then for each $a\in A$ the map $B\rightarrow C: b\mapsto f(a,b)$ is also continuous.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This may be trivial, but do you mind clarifying formally how "by definition $act_$ is a continuous map"? For example, in a metric space, how does $|gx_0-gx|$ relate to $|x-x_0|<\delta$ if I want to show that the former is less than $\epsilon$?